# Proxying for assets and some feature pages to legacy app

Tags: nginx

Right now we have our servers set up so that traffic comes through .NET servers,
and requests to our Node server for the React bits. I'm trying to switch our dev
and staging environments to the other way around, so everything goes through our
Node app first, and proxies to the legacy servers for anything we haven't done
in React yet.

This setup involves the .NET (legacy) servers, AWS, TeamCity, and a host of
other things I've never touched before, so there's a chance I've got something
wrong somewhere else, but I'm pretty sure it's the NGINX conf that's causing me
trouble.

Right now most content is rendered correctly, but we have a lot of assets served
by the legacy app that aren't being fetched. For example, we have a CSS file
that, when requested, actually returns a 200 response, but shows our 404 page.

This is the relevant nginx.conf. The commented-out location on line 38 didn't
seem to do anything different than the line below it. Essentially all paths that
aren't in line 24, I need to be fetching from the legacy app. Any thoughts?

```
upstream nodeserver {
  server 127.0.0.1:4010;
}

resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=5s;

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.stagingserver.com render.dev.stagingserver.com;

    set $legacy "dev.stagingserver.com/";

  location ~* \.js {
    gzip_static on;
    root /web/public;
  }

  location ~* \.css {
    gzip_static on;
    root /web/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @legacy;
  }

  location ~* ^/(these|are|features|served|by|nodeserver)/ {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://nodeserver;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    # location ~* ^/(these|features|are|on|legacy|server)/ {
    location / {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://$legacy;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cookie_domain $legacy $host;
  }

  location @legacy {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://$legacy$request_uri/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  error_page 404 @legacy;

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 507 508 509 /maintenance.html;
  location = /maintenance.html {
    root /web;
    internal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being partially the scheme, partially what I was setting legacy to, and partially that 127.0.0.1 isn't what I thought it was. Here's the setup that ended up working for us.

```
upstream nodeserver {
  server nodeserver-docker-image-name:4010;
}

resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;

map $http_x_forwarded_proto $forwarded_scheme {
  default $scheme;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name dev.stagingserver.com render.dev.stagingserver.com;

  set $legacy "dev.stagingserver-aws-internal-dns.com";

  location ~* ^/(all|relevant|features) {
    proxy_pass http://nodeserver;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @legacy;
  }

  location @legacy {
    proxy_pass $forwarded_scheme://$legacy$request_uri;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_cookie_domain $legacy dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host dev.stagingserver.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 507 508 509 /maintenance.html;
  location = /maintenance.html {
    root /web;
    internal;
  }
}
```